# SonarQube does not create graphs on project dashboards

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube Metrics graphs are not being displayed on my project dashboards behind the total numbers and Quality Gate ratings. 
[image: list of analyses]

Current versions of SonarQube and plugins and MySQL 5.7. I am creating a new SQ project through its Administration->Projects->Management->Create Project and then performing analyses as follows (anything capitalized is either a variable or anonymized): *

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:KEY /v:VERSION /d:sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/ /d:sonar.login=TOKEN /d:sonar.projectDate=YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+0000
MSBuild.exe /maxcpucount /nr:false /nologo /target:rebuild /verbosity:quiet PROJECT\PROJECT.sln
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end /d:sonar.login=TOKEN
```

I have tried VERSION equal to a constant value "1.0" and VERSION equal to a string of the UNIX time (seconds since 1/1/1970) of each git commit I analyze. I've also tried configuring project leak periods of the last 90 days and also previous_analysis, though I think that would only affect the graphs in the right column. If someone could tell me what I am doing incorrectly, I would appreciate it.

* These are examples of the commands executed by a Python script that is iterating over a list of git commit hashes and their associated timestamps, in increasing order, to populate the project history. The python script in turn is mimicking a Jenkins job that will eventually take over calling SonarQube.

Background Tasks page:[image: background tasks]

Comment: Post screenshots of your project home page, and your list (in SQ) of analyses?

Comment: Screenshots added to original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project homepage screenshot shows the graph in the leak period, but not extending left into the Overall section.

This is going to be a question of your analysis date and your definition of "leak period". If your leak period is set to `previous_version`, then you need to take a look at the `sonar.version` values in your analyses. So far, it looks like all your analyses are leak period analyses, which is why nothing has filtered left into the overall view.